# Mask with ring polygon in R?

Tags: r, extract-by-mask

I'm trying to mask a raster with a ring polygon using the function raster::mask, but only recognizes the outer edges of the polygon, can anyone help me with this?
I only need the pixels within the yellow area, but it returns pixel inside the outer edge of the polygon.

```
library(raster)

raster<-raster("my_raster_path")  
buffer<-shapefile("my_shapefile_path") #yellow buffer

output<-mask(raster, buffer)
writeRaster(output, "filename") #output grayscale raster
```

[image: I only need the pixels within the yellow area]

Comment: How about you divide the task in two steps? First the outer, then the inner clip?

Comment: Thanks Erik. How can I clip the inner section?

Comment: I guess like the other operation, simply separate your mask into two parts.

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Is this image an overlay of the clipped raster (grayscale) and the polygon (yellow with opacity) showing (with the red X) the bit that hasn't been clipped out? It looks a bit of a mess and could do with the explanation.

Comment: Yes, the image is an overlay of  the output raster (grayscale) and the polygon (yellow with opacity). All the pixels outside the yellow polygon haven't been clipped out. Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Can't do this without your data or something that shows the same problem.

Comment: It looks like some set of polygons in your shapefile overlap to form a continuous border around the region you wish to mask. I'm not sure what raster::mask does with the vector data you give it; if it unions it then you'll need to call mask for each feature in your geometry. On the other hand if you've unioned your data then that's the issue.